# Hibernate reverse query on Many to Many self join

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have an entity like below:

```
public class Item {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "ITEM_DEPENDENCIES", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id"), @JoinColumn(name = "version") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dependencyid"), @JoinColumn(name = "dependencyversion") })
    private Set<Item> dependencies;
    //....getters and setters...
}

@Embeddable
public class Id implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "version")
    private String version;
    //....getters and setters...
}
```

Each item can have multiple dependencies and each dependency can be referred by multiple items. Thus I have tried to create a self reference table ITEM_DEPENDENCIES which is created successfully by hibernate.

Now one use case needs to find all items which have a particular dependency. For example:

[image]

I want to write a query to get all the items which have c and d as dependency. i.e. a,b and g,h.

I am trying to write a query in a spring repository but not able to reach to a solution. Please guide if my design is correct then how to write this query or if I need to redesign the tables in a better way.

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Id>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Item> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT contents " //
            + "FROM Item contents join Item.dependencies dependencies " //
            + "WHERE dependencies.id.id = :id " //
            + "AND dependencies.id.version = :version")
    List<Item> findByDependency(String id, String version);
}
```

Comment: `join contents.dependencies dependencies`.

Comment: Bang! that solved the problem. Many Thanks. :)